# Questions of the Proof of Kolmogorov's Strong Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, law-of-large-numbers

From the Book of Jacod-Protter (Probability Essentials).

> Theorem: Let $(X_j)$ be an independent and identically distributed sequence with $E\{|X_j|\} < \infty$. Then
> \begin{equation*}
>    \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_1+ \cdots + X_n}{n} = E\{X_1\} \text{ a.s.}
>   \end{equation*}
>
> > Some part of the proof: Let $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$, and $\mathcal{F}_{-n} = σ(S_n, S_{n+1}, S_{n+2}, . . .)$. Then $\mathcal{F}_{-n} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{-m}$ if $n ≥ m$, and the process
> > $$M_{-n} = E\{X_1|\mathcal{F}_{−n}\}$$
> > is a backwards martingle. Note that $E\{M_n\} = E\{X_1\}$, each $n$. Also note that by symmetry for $1 ≤ j ≤ n:$
> > $$E\{X_1|\mathcal{F}_{−n}\} = E\{X_j|\mathcal{F}_{−n}\} ~~~~ a.s.$$ Therefore
> > $$M_{-n} = E\{X_1|\mathcal{F}_{−n}\} = E\{X_2|\mathcal{F}_{−n}\} = \cdots = E\{X_n|\mathcal{F}_{−n}\},$$
> > hence
> > $$M_{−n} =\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n E\{X_j|\mathcal{F}_{−n}\} = E\left\{ \frac{S_n}{n}|\mathcal{F}_{-n}\right\} = \frac{S_n}{n} ~~~ a.s.$$

Query:

1. How can this process $M_{-n} = E\{X_1|\mathcal{F}_{−n}\}$ be backwards martingle? Is this because we have our $(\mathcal{F}_{-n})$ is an increasing sequence and $M_{-n} = E\{X_1|\mathcal{F}_{−n}\}$ is somewhat look like on the definition of the backwards martingle but in this case $M_{-n}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{-n}-$measurable?
2. In this part $$E\{X_1|\mathcal{F}_{−n}\} = E\{X_j|\mathcal{F}_{−n}\} ~~~~ a.s.,$$ the book gave the hint that use the result in Exercise 23.17 .

> Exercise 23.17 Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be an i.i.d. and in $L^p$. Let $S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n X_J$ and $\mathcal{F}_ = \sigma(S_n, S_{n+1}, S_{n+2}, \ldots)$. Show that $E\{X_1|\mathcal{F}_n\} = E\{X_1|S_n\}$ and also $E\{X_j|\mathcal{F}_n\} = E\{X_j|S_n\}$ for $1\leq j \leq n$. Also show that $E\{X_j|\mathcal{F}_n\} = E\{X_1|S_n\}$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$.

My attempt: $E\{X_1|\mathcal{F}_{-n}\} = E\{X_1|S_n\} = E\{X_j|\mathcal{F}_{-n}\}$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$.

However, in the said problem, it does not say about its almost surely but on the proof, it is equal almost surely. Could you please show why it is almost surely?

3. And lastly, from the proof, we have
   $$E\left\{ \frac{S_n}{n}|\mathcal{F}_{-n}\right\} = \frac{S_n}{n} ~~~ a.s.$$
   Could you please show me how is this equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- First, note that a backward martingale is a martingale for which indices start from $-\infty$ towards 0. The filtration $(\mathcal{F}_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^{-}}$ is also increasing in the sense: $\mathcal{F}_{n}\subset\mathcal{F}_{n+1}$. We also have $M_{n} = \mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F_{n}}]$ (n is negative) which corresponds exactly to the definition of martingale. So what you described is correct.

2- Note that the conditional expectation is always defined almost surely. So what is meant by equality in the hint is rather equality a.e.

3- By definition of $\mathcal{F}_{-n}$, $S_{n}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{-n}-$measurable, so its conditional expectation is equal to itself (a.e of course).

Comment: Thank you, this helps me a lot understanding this proof.

Comment: Hello sir @Ibra, I have a question. 
After that, it says that using backwards martingale convergence theorem, 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}E\{\frac{S_n}{n} | S+n, S_{n+1}, ...\}=X,$$
with $E\{X} = E\{X_1\}$.

However, the theorem says that $(X_{-n})$ converges a.s. to $X$, how to use the said theorem to this? Thank you sir.

Comment: M(-n) = Sn/n is a backward martingale, so it converges a.e and in L1 towards a variable X having the same expectation as M(-n) which is also equal to the expectation of X_{1}(look at the definition of M_{-n}). The expectation of lthe limit X is equal to that of M(-n) because the convergence takes place also in L1.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. You are very helpful.